# looping and sentinel values

Tags: python, sentinel

I am trying to find average of inputted numbers by a user. The loop is supposed to repeat itself until the user inputs -9999 (sentinel value) this is what i have so far and it works in idle but the program doesnt end an give me the average when i type -9999. I am new to python and could use a little guidance thank you.

```
import random

numbers = [int(input("Please, enter number {}(-9999 to end")

if input("-9999"):

# will display prompt like "Please, enter number 1:"
print ("numbers entered:", numbers) # this will print the entered number

positives = [num for num in numbers if num > 0]
negatives = [num for num in numbers if num < 0]

# loop ends here

print ("Average negative number is :", sum(negatives)*1.0/len(negatives))
print ("Average positive number is :", sum(positives)*1.0/len(positives))
print ("Average of all numbers is:",sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
```

Comment: The line `if input("-9999")` does *not* check whether or not the user has just entered the text `9999` into your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
ns = []
while not ns or ns[-1] != -9999:
    ns.append(int(input("Please, enter number {}(-9999 to end"))))
```

Comment: thank you... how do you i not include the value -9999 in my averages? it works to end the program but it includes it in my averages and throws it off

Comment: Based on the level of complexity of this problem, I think it would be helpful to give some explanation on how the value of `not ns` is evaluated.

Comment: @user32152 ns.pop(-1) will remove last -9999

Answer (score 0):

```
ns = list(iter(lambda:int(input("Enter Number:")),-9999))
```

is a cool way to do it

iter can take a sentinal value to wait for as a second argument, if you use a function for the first argument

as an aside with your positive and negatives .... it seems it will ignore zeros (which may be intentional)...

Answer (score 0):

This code will loop while you add numbers to your list and stop when you enter -9999. It will then throw the -9999 away so you can get on with your averaging. It's not compact, but it works and it's simple.

```
numbers = []

while True:
    numbers.append(input("Enter a number: "))   #append user input to 'numbers'
    if numbers[-1] == -9999:     #check to see if the last number entered was -9999
        numbers = numbers[:-1]   #if it was, modify numbers to exclude it
        break                    # and break the loop
```